# Excel Pivot Table wrong to calculate Yearly Average (Based on Monthly Data)

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9su1.png) [Pivot Table Generated]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp57n.png) [Data Used]

I have monthly data and want to summarize the subtotal (the red cells) with right calculation. Excel calculate yearly average (on column AP) by dividing sum of monthly average with 12 (on column AP), rather than adjusting it with number of days on each month.

The correct average is shown on column AQ. How to change the result (red cells) on Column AP (pivot table) with values shown on column AQ?

Comment: Change the calculation used in the pivot table to that used in column AQ.

Comment: I'm sorry, how to do that?